# Trying to get a basic C shell to do a simple pipe()

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe, piping

I am trying to create a simple c shell. The only thing I can't get to work is the piping. I just need one pipe (i.e. "ls | wc -l"). I can't find anything where someone does this by reading the arguments from command line, any help would be greatly appreciated. I need help getting a second set of arguments that is after the "|" right now if I had the argument "ls | wc -l" I would get "ls" stored in args2 but I need "wc -l" to be in args3 so I can execvp() them separately.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define HISTORY_COUNT 20
char *prompt = "% ";

int
main()
{
int pid;
//int child_pid;
char line[81];
char *token;
char *separator = " \t\n";
char **args;
char **args2;
char **args3;
char cmd[100];
char *hp;
char *cp;
char *ifile;
char *ofile;
int check;
int pfds[2];
int i;
int j;
int current = 0;
int p = 0;
//int check;
char *hist[HISTORY_COUNT];
//char history[90];
//typedef void (*sighandler_t) (int);

args = malloc(80 * sizeof(char *));
args2 = malloc(80 * sizeof(char *));
while (1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", prompt);
    fflush(stderr);

    if (fgets(line, 80, stdin) == NULL)
        break;
    // split up the line

    i = 0;
    while (1) {
        token = strtok((i == 0) ? line : NULL, separator);
        if (token == NULL)
            break;
        args[i++] = token;
              /* build command array */

    }
    args[i] = NULL;
    // assume no redirections
    ofile = NULL;
    ifile = NULL;

    // split off the redirections
    j = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (1) {        //stackoverflow.com/questions/35569673
        cp = args[i++];
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        switch (*cp) {
        case '<':
            if (cp[1] == 0)
                cp = args[i++];
            else
                ++cp;
            ifile = cp;
            break;

        case '>':
            if (cp[1] == 0)
                cp = args[i++];
            else
                ++cp;
            ofile = cp;
            break;
    case '|':               //I need this case to put the commands following
                              the pipe into a variable
    if(cp[1] ==0){
       cp = args[i++];

    printf("%s\n", cp);
       if(pipe(pfds) == -1){
           perror("Broken Pipe");
           exit(1);
       }
       //args3[j++] = cp;
       p = 1;
    }
    else{ 
       ++cp;
       printf("DOES THIS HAPPEN\n");
               //

    }
       break;

        default:
            args2[j++] = cp;
    args3[cp++] = cp
            break;
        }
    }
    args2[j] = NULL;
    if (j == 0)
        continue;

    switch (pid = fork()) {
    case 0:
        // open stdin
        if (ifile != NULL) {
            int fd = open(ifile, O_RDONLY);

            if (dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "dup2 failed");
            }

            close(fd);
        }


        // open stdout
        if (ofile != NULL) {
            // args[1] = NULL;
            int fd2;


            if ((fd2 = open(ofile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644)) < 0) {
                perror("couldn't open output file.");
                exit(0);
            }

            // args+=2;
            printf("okay");
            dup2(fd2, STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd2);
        }


    if(p == 1){        //from stackoverflow.com/questions/2784500
    printf("Welcome to the party\n");
    close(1);
    dup(pfds[1]);
    close(pfds[0]);
    execvp(args2[0], args2);
    break;
    }


    if(strcmp(args2[0], "cd") == 0){            //cd command
        if(args2[1] == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument");
        }
        else{
    //printf("Is this happening");
        check = chdir(args2[1]);
    //printf("What abuot this");
    if(check != 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s",prompt);

    }
        }
    break;
          }
        if (strcmp(args2[0], "history") == 0){

        int i = 0;
        int hist_num = 1;
    //printf("%d\n", current);
        do {
                if (hist[i]) {
                        printf("%4d  %s\n", hist_num, hist[i]);
                        hist_num++;
                }

                i = (i + 1) % HISTORY_COUNT;

        } while (i != current);

          break;
    }
        execvp(args2[0], args2);        /* child */
        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR %s no such program\n", line);
        exit(1);
        break;

    case -1:
        /* unlikely but possible if hit a limit */
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR can't create child process!\n");
        break;

    default:
        //printf("am I here");
    if(p==1){
        close(0);
        dup(pfds[0]);
        close(pfds[1]);
        //execvp();
    }
        wait(NULL);
        //waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
    }
}

exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Please tell us *specifically* what is wrong with your program or which part of it you need help with. You have just dumped a whole lot of code and expect everyone to work out what it does, which parts work, which parts don't work and which bits you want help with. "I can't find anything where someone does this": Variants of this question gets asked pretty much every day.

Comment: I have tried to make it more clear. @kaylum